# Improper integral of a function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to study the nature of an improper integral. I separate the integral from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $\infty$.
The first integral is divergent (I proved that it is equivalent to Riemann integral, which is divergent in the neighborhood of $0$). But I didn't find how I can prove the convergence or divergence of the second one.
The integral can be found below:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)^2}{\sin^2x}e^{-x}\ \text d x$$

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty big picture for such a small formula...

Comment: You are wrong about the divergence near $0$. The integrand is continuous near $0$

Comment: Also, if you claim (wrongly) that it diverges near $0$, what's the point of studying the behaviour elsewhere? You already know that it diverges

Comment: To add to @Fredrico, what is the point of splitting the integral at $x=1$ if you believe it to diverge at $0$?

Answer (score 0):

The integrand has a singularity at every value $x=k\pi.$  And it will diverge at each of those values.

Comment: No, at $0$ it doesn't diverge. The integrand tends to $1$. The rest is correct though

Comment: at 0 we use the equivalent we have that ln(1+x)² is equivalent to 2x and sin²x is equivanlent to x² and exp(x) is equivalent to 1 so the above integral is equivalent to 2x/x²=2/x and the integral of 2/x from 0 to a real number diverge ( This is when we separate the integral into integrals the first one is from 0 to 1 and the second from 1 to infini

Comment: @MohammedMohammed Just plot your integrand. You will see that it does not diverge at $0$. Even if it did, what is the point of splitting the integral at $x=1$?

Comment: Near $0$, $\ln^2(1+x)\approx x^2$, so the integral actually has an integrable singularity.